# How do I exit "guided mode"?

Tags: support, asking-questions, ask-question-wizard-2018

Out of curiosity I clicked on "Use guided mode" when I was about to ask a question on Stack Overflow, and now I can't find a way to turn it off.

How do I get back to the normal question form?

Comment: So I just enabled guided mode, hoping to take a screenshot of the obvious "disable" button, but I can't find it...

Comment: @Stijn you need to pick an item on the list to get to the exit button. Slightly horrible design.

Comment: Alternatively: append "?guided=false" after you mistakenly enter guided mode example link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=false